Positive integer sequence with sum $m$ can have at most $\left\lfloor\dfrac{m^2}{8}\right\rfloor$ increasing pairs

Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be a sequence of positive integers such that
$\bullet$ $a_1+\cdots+a_n=m$;
$\bullet$ The number of pairs $(i,j)$ such that $i<j$ and $a_i<a_j$ is $k$.
Must we have
$$
k\le \dfrac{m^2}{8}?
$$

The relation $k\le \dfrac{m^2}{8}$ is based on the following two observations:
Observation 1. If $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ consists of only $1$'s and $2$'s, then we have $k\le \dfrac{m^2}{8}$, and the result is optimal.
Proof. WLOG we can suppose that the last term in the sequence is $2$. Suppose that there are $t$ $2$'s, and the number of $1$'s to the left of each $2$ is $b_1,\cdots,b_t$, then
$$
b_1\le \cdots\le b_t,\quad m=b_t+2t,\quad k=b_1+\cdots+b_t.
$$
We then have $k\le tb_t\le\dfrac{(b_t+2t)^2}{8}=\dfrac{m^2}{8}$. Moreover, it is possible that $k=\left\lfloor\dfrac{m^2}{8}\right\rfloor$: Let $t$ be the integer closest to $\dfrac{m}{4}$ (choose either one in case of a tie), and
$$
b_1=\cdots=b_t = m-2t,
$$
which means that we pick the sequence consisting of $m-2t$ $1$'s followed by $t$ $2$'s. Then we have $k=t(m-2t)$, and we see that
\begin{align*}
m\equiv 0\,(\operatorname{mod}\,4)&\Rightarrow t=\dfrac{m}{4}\Rightarrow k=\dfrac{m^2}{8};\\
m\equiv 1\,(\operatorname{mod}\,4)&\Rightarrow t=\dfrac{m-1}{4}\Rightarrow k=\dfrac{m^2-1}{8};\\
m\equiv 2\,(\operatorname{mod}\,4)&\Rightarrow t=\dfrac{m-2}{4}\text{ or }\dfrac{m+2}{4}\Rightarrow k=\dfrac{m^2-4}{8};\\
m\equiv 3\,(\operatorname{mod}\,4)&\Rightarrow t=\dfrac{m+1}{4}\Rightarrow k=\dfrac{m^2-1}{8},
\end{align*}
so $k=\left\lfloor\dfrac{m^2}{8}\right\rfloor$ in this case.
Note 1.1. We can see that $k=0,\cdots,\left\lfloor\dfrac{m^2}{8}\right\rfloor$ are all possible because a nonincreasing sequence corresponds to $k=0$, and swapping two adjacent entries in a sequence would leave $m$ unchanged, but $k$ changed by $0$ or $\pm 1$.
Note 1.2. The construction above gives the only optimal solutions. Indeed, if $k=\left\lfloor\dfrac{m^2}{8}\right\rfloor$, then
$$
t(m-2t)=tb_t\ge k=\left\lfloor\dfrac{m^2}{8}\right\rfloor\Rightarrow \left|t-\dfrac{m}{4}\right|\le\dfrac{1}{2}, k=tb_t\text{ (hence }b_1=\cdots=b_t).
$$
Observation 2. If $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ is nondecreasing, then $k\le\dfrac{m^2}{8}$, and the result is also optimal.
Proof. Suppose that each of $1,2,\cdots$ occurs $c_1,c_2,\cdots$ times in the sequence, where $c_i\neq 0$ for finitely many $i$, then
$$
m=c_1+2c_2+\cdots,\quad k=\sum_{i<j}c_ic_j=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}c_ic_j,
$$
so we have
$$
m^2 - 8k = (c_1 - 2c_2 - c_3)^2 + 8c_3^2 + \sum^{\infty}_{i=4}i^2c_i^2+\sum_{\max\{i,j\}\ge 4,i\neq j}(ij-4)c_ic_j\ge 0.
$$
The result $k\le\dfrac{m^2}{8}$ for nondecreasing sequences is also optimal as shown by the $1-2$ sequences above.
Note 2.1. If the equality holds, then we must have $c_3=c_4=\cdots=0$, otherwise we would have $m^2-8k\ge 8c_i^2\ge 8$.
I don't have any idea for the general case. I guess that if $k$ attains its maximum with $m$ fixed, then $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ must consist of only $1$'s and $2$'s, but I don't know how to prove it. Any help appreciated.
Edit. This question turns out to be trivial. For a general sequence, we apply the process of bubble sort. At each step either we do nothing, either we create a new increasing pair, so $k$ reaches its maximum when and only when the sequence is nondecreasing, and the result $k\le\dfrac{m^2}{8}$ follows from Observation 2 above.

I'm a bit confused about what exactly you're asking. Are you only interested in the last point in bold?

For your note 1.1, you seem to be requiring $ i < j$ with $a_i < a_j$. However, that is not stated in your conditions.

Given that, it seems to me that you have all of the elements of the proof (and my proof follows along your lines, with a slightly different approach to Observation 2). If you can clarify what your confusion is about, we might be able to help clean it up.

It seems to work for $n=3$.

@CalvinLin Yes, my bad. This question turns out to be trivial. Thanks for working on it anyway!

As I pointed out in the comments,

the order of the sequence $a_i$ doesn't matter. Any rearrangement of them will lead to the same number of (unordered) pairs $(a_i, a_j)$
I believe that OP has all of the elements required for the proof. As such, this solution can be considered a restatement/refinement of what they presented.

Let's rephrase the question slightly (which OP did in observation 2), which will make this much easier to approach:

Given $a_i$ a squence of positive integers that sum to $m$, let there be $b_1$ 1's, $b_2$ 2's, etc up to $b_n $ n's (the max of the positive integers), so $ \sum i b_i = m$.
Show that $ \sum_{i\neq j} b_i b_ j \leq \frac{m^2 }{ 8}$.

Consider a sequence of $b_i$ that maximizes $ \sum b_i b_j$.
Show that it must have the following properties.

There are at least 2 non-zero values.
$b_i$ is a non-increasing sequence.
$b_3 = b_4 = \ldots = b_n  = 0 $.


 In particular, if $b_3 \neq 0$, show that $b_1^* = b_1 + b_3, b_2^* = b_2 + b_3, b_3^* = 0, b_i ^* = b_i$ would increase the summation.


$b_1 b_2 \leq \frac{m^2}{8}$.

Hence the desired result is true.
